# Running a tool in its own cmd.exe

Tags: java, windows, cmd

I am working on a Java application which will be used to launch other applications. Now, most of those have a GUI, but some are command-line tools. For the latter, I would like to open the appropriate command line and have them execute there.

That is, on Windows, I would like to open cmd.exe, and run the tool with the appropriate arguments. The problem is getting cmd.exe to stay open.

When I use ProcessBuilder to start

```
cmd.exe /k java -version
```

I get the desired output (I capture the output streams), but the cmd.exe window isn't visible.

When I run

```
cmd.exe /k start java -version
```

the cmd.exe window pops up for a split second and then disappears.

But when I just run `cmd.exe /k start` the cmd.exe window appears and stays open, while `cmd.exe start` doesn't show a window (as I would expect).

What I want is for the command line tool to run in its own cmd.exe and stay open for input.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Starting a Java tool with cmd.exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782129/starting-a-java-tool-with-cmd-exe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved using the answer in ["Starting a Java tool with cmd.exe"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782129/starting-a-java-tool-with-cmd-exe). I suspected the problems were separate, but they were not.

Comment: I will, but I am not currently allowed to by Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Running this from the cmd.exe works.

```
cmd start cmd /k java -version
```

However, this just waits for you to run more cmd's.

If you want it to wait for user input use

```
cmd start java MyProgramWhichWaitsForInput
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be doing much at all. It just opens a new cmd.exe and I get the regular `Microsoft Windows [Version 5.2.3790]` etc. output which you get when you just start cmd.exe.

Comment: The first example, displays the `java -version` output followed by the `cmd.exe` prompt which is what I would expect it to do reading the `help cmd` page. If you mean the second example, can you post your java code.