# Starting a Java tool with cmd.exe

Tags: java, cmd

I am trying to start a Java command line tool in its own cmd.exe window from Java. I use ProcessBuilder to start the following:

```
cmd.exe /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\JavaSoft\jre\1.5.0_07\bin\java.exe"
```

This works. This also works:

```
cmd.exe /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\JavaSoft\jre\1.5.0_07\bin\java.exe" -version
```

But when I try to run the following

```
cmd.exe /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\JavaSoft\jre\1.5.0_07\bin\java.exe" "test a"
```

I get an error saying it can't find "C:\Program". I expected to get an exception from java.exe. I need to be able to use quotation marks in some of the arguments. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Like in your previous question on the same topic. I don't think `/k` does what you think.

Comment: cmd.exe /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\JavaSoft\jre\1.5.0_07\bin\java.exe test a"   how about if you do this way?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no reason to use cmd.exe. Just start java.exe directly

Comment: It's a command line tool which needs input from the user. Right now I'm leaning towards writing a simple textual input/output window in Java and using that. It'll be cross-platform to boot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From "cmd /?":

> 1. If all of the following conditions are met, then quote characters on the
>      command line are preserved:
>
>    - no /S switch
>    - exactly two quote characters
>    - no special characters between the two quote characters, where special is
>        one of: &<>()@^|
>    - there are one or more whitespace characters between the the two quote
>        characters
>    - the string between the two quote characters is the name of an
>        executable file.
> 2. Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is a quote
>      character and if so, strip the leading
>      character and remove the last quote
>      character on the command line,
>      preserving any text after the last
>      quote character.

Okay, that explains why it doesn't work if there are more than two quotes. But that doesn't explain how exactly to solve the problem. Thankfully, Google [has the answer](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html):

```
cmd.exe /k ""d:\laj soft\java.exe" "test a""
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

> java -jar your_jar_archive.jar

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over where your JDK is installed, its a good idea to install it in a location that does not contain spaces. "Program Files" is the default location on Windows but it almost always leads to problems.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the old DOS trick for this one. Refer to Program Files as progra~1. This usually gets me around the problem.

Comment: It would probably solve the problem with starting cmd, but that wouldn't allow the OP to pass arguments containing spaces, which is what he wants.